# Hand-made Program about Menu of a restaurant Java

Tags: java

Hello everybody my code is this for a restaurant menu about burger that i just thought of making combining checkbox and radio buttons....My output is 0.0 for some reason and I do not know why...can somebody plz tell me what I am doing wrong????

CODE :

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RMenu extends JFrame
{
final double TAX = 0.06;
private JTextField t, a;
private JCheckBox Lettuce, Mustard ,Cheese , Tomatoes , Onions , Jalapeno , Pickels;
private JRadioButton Ham, Steak , Chicken , Pork;
private ButtonGroup  g;
double total = 0.00;


public RMenu()
{
super( "Menu of our Restaurant for Burger");
Container c = getContentPane();
c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

t = new JTextField ( " Welcome to our burger restauraunt",26);
t.setFont( new Font( "TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 10 ) );
t.setEditable(false);
c.add(t);

Lettuce = new JCheckBox( "Lettuce");
c.add(Lettuce);
Mustard = new JCheckBox("Mustard");
c.add(Mustard);
Cheese =  new JCheckBox("Cheese");
c.add(Cheese);
Tomatoes = new JCheckBox("Tomatoes");
c.add(Tomatoes);
Onions = new JCheckBox("Onions");
c.add(Onions);
Jalapeno = new JCheckBox("Jalapeno");
c.add(Jalapeno);
Pickels = new JCheckBox("Pickels");
c.add(Pickels);
Ham = new JRadioButton("Ham",false);
c.add(Ham);
Steak = new JRadioButton("Steak",false);
c.add(Steak);
Chicken = new JRadioButton("Chicken",false);
c.add(Chicken);
Pork = new JRadioButton("Pork",false);
c.add(Pork);

g = new ButtonGroup();
g.add(Ham);
g.add(Steak);
g.add(Chicken);
g.add(Pork);

CheckBoxHandler handler1 = new CheckBoxHandler();
Lettuce.addItemListener(handler1);
Mustard.addItemListener(handler1);
Cheese.addItemListener(handler1);
Tomatoes.addItemListener(handler1);
Onions.addItemListener(handler1);
Jalapeno.addItemListener(handler1);
Pickels.addItemListener(handler1);

RadioButtonHandler handler = new RadioButtonHandler();
Ham.addItemListener(handler);
Steak.addItemListener(handler);
Chicken.addItemListener(handler);
Pork.addItemListener(handler);

setSize(400,400);
setVisible(true);

a = new JTextField(" Your total amount is : $" + total,20);
a.setEditable(false);
c.add(a);
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    RMenu app = new RMenu();
    app.addWindowListener
      (
         new WindowAdapter() 
         {
            public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
            {
               System.exit( 0 );
            }
         }
      );

}



private class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener 
{

     public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e )
     {

         if (e.getSource() == Lettuce)
             if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                 total += 0.95;
        if (e.getSource() == Mustard)
            if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                total += 0.85;
         if (e.getSource() == Cheese)
             if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                 total+= 0.45;
         if (e.getSource() == Tomatoes)
             if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                 total += 1.05;
         if (e.getSource() == Onions)
             if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                 total += 0.55;
         if (e.getSource() == Jalapeno)
             if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                 total += 0.35;
         if (e.getSource() == Pickels)
             if ( e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED )
                 total +=0.65;

     }



}

private class RadioButtonHandler implements ItemListener 
{
      public void itemStateChanged( ItemEvent e )
      {
         if (e.getSource()== Ham)
             total = total + 4.95 + 4.95*TAX;
         else if (e.getSource() == Steak)
             total = total + 5.05 + 5.05*TAX;
         else if (e.getSource() == Chicken)
             total = total + 3.75 + 3.75 *TAX;
         else if (e.getSource()== Pork)
             total = total + 6.25 + 6.25*TAX;

      }

  }
}
```

Comment: **when ?where ? what ?**

Comment: From what I can see, you're not outputting anything at all. Is this all the code?

Comment: Why don't you develop a web-based solution?

Answer (score 3):

You are updating the value of `total` but never again assigning that value to `a` `TextField`
In `itemStateChanged` method of both the listener classes, after then end of all `if`s, set the value of `a`, like `a.setText("Total is "+total);`
Also, you will have to move `a` outside the method and make it as an instance variable so that it can be accessed elsewhere.

Suggestion: Its always good to follow naming conventions. `a` or `t` doesn't give a meaningful name to the components that you are using.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: updated to sound that as an answer :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mubin...I just named them like that because i didnt feel like naming them nothing else :P.....I will try do that as you mentioned and I just made a self program to remind myself how to make a simple window with radiobuttons and checkboxes because i have not done them for a long time